# Is there a way to combine 2 pretrained tensorflow Models?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, ensemble-learning

I have trained a TensorFlow classification model.
Same model with different loaded weights classifies different classes better.

Is it possible to combine same model with different weights to increase its performance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine both their results by averaging out the final logits. Then, finding the final classification.

Comment: Yes averaging will do.
Is there any way in Tf to do linear combination of multiple models to get good results?

Comment: It's a simple addition operation. You don't require to optimize that. I normally add the logits. Though, you can try with `tf.reduce_mean` and then, use the result for finding out the class.